# Скрытие класса при нажатии на кнопку

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Почему при активации всплывающего окна изображение лежит поверх формы обратного звонка?
Как сделать, чтобы слои были упорядочены?
При нажатии на кнопку "Перезвоните мне" происходит данная ситуация, пытался корректировать z-index, эффекта нет.
Ссылка на сайт: http://vcland.wg3036.wg01.ru
Код приложен: `codepen.io/MorrisJerrald/pen/OeXaMw`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

у вас элемент `#cmbf-form-container-110` (попап с формой обратного звонка) лежит ВНУТРИ блока с кнопкой, которая его вызывает. А он лежит ВНУТРИ секции `#section-id-1560682431859`, которая лежит НА ОДНОМ УРОВНЕ с остальными секциями, в т.ч. теми, в которых есть дальнейший контент.

Так вот, `z-index` у всплывающего окна работает внутри его родителей, но не подействует на "дядей" и "двоюродных братьев". Например в конструкции:

```
<section id="1">
    <div id="A" style="z-index:999"></div>
    <div id="B"></div>
<section>

<section id="2">
    <div id="C" style="z-index:1"></div>
    <div id="D"></div>
<section>
```

элемент `#A` будет располагаться поверх любого элемента В ПРЕДЕЛАХ секции `#1`, а содержимое секции `#2` его все равно перекроет. Z-index - свойство НЕ глобальное.

Правильное решение - вынести модальный блок за пределы секции с контентом в конец документа.

Костыль - задать `z-index` для секции, в которой находится этот блок так, чтобы она была выше прочих (но не менять ее `position`).

П.С. код на codepen у вас нерабочий, выдает черт-те что распёртое и кучу ошибок в консоль.